# Devexpress GridView Show/Hide Search bar (ctrl + f) button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

What I'm trying to do is to have a button that will execute command "ctrl + f" to find data inside gridview.

I have this:

```
Private Sub butEmpSearch_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs)
        If GridView1.IsFindPanelVisible Then
            GridView1.ShowFindPanel()
        Else
            GridView1.HideFindPanel()
        End If
    End Sub
```

However it doesn't display search bar in first place. Any ideas how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now.
The correct code was:

```
Private Sub butEmpSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butEmpSearch.Click
        If Not GridView1.IsFindPanelVisible Then
            GridView1.ShowFindPanel()
        Else
            GridView1.HideFindPanel()
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how to make it work?

You've just used the wrong (opposite) condition.

This

```
If GridView1.IsFindPanelVisible Then
```

should be

```
If Not GridView1.IsFindPanelVisible Then
```